# Getting the DI container in dotnetcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to get an instance of a route in the startup configuration of my app by using the DI container and not hardcode the instance, is there a way to do that?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         // hardcoded dependeny, I'd like to do something like this
         // var instance = container.getInstance<LandingPageRouter>();
         routes.Routes.Add(new LandingPageRouter(routes, new MyWebRequest()));
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<LandingPageRouter>()`?

If that doesn't work, it implies the controller isn't a registered service yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm getting this exception: "No service for type 'Main.Config.LandingPageRouter' has been registered."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If it isn't in the DI container, it implies it isn't registered as a service. You can try doing `services.AddScoped<LandingPageRouter>();` before this, inside the `ConfigureServices` method of your startup class.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add it at the registration time so I registered it with addTransient, can you explain the difference between AddScoped?

Comment: `AddTransient` will always return a new instance of your service. `AddScoped` will only return one instance per httpcontext. In either case, if your service implements `IDisposable`, it will automatically be disposed by the DI container.